# .change(function() { doesn't alert an option value after changing options of select menu

Tags: jquery, clone, onchange, select-menu

the following call function doesn't alert an option value after changing options of select menu:

**doesn't give alert:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){       
    $(".selectmenu").scrollectBox({                           
        preset: 'dropdown',
        numVisibleOptions: 4,
        scrollInterval: 150, 
        scrollOn: 'hover',
        listWidth: 160,
        onSelectEvent: null

}).change(function() {
   var optionvalue = $("select.selectmenu").val(); 
   alert('Selected value ' + optionvalue);     
 });
});

</script>
```

but the following change function independently give's an alert

**gives alert:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function($){    
      $(".selectmenu").change(function() {
       var optionvalue = $("select.selectmenu").val(); 
     alert('Selected value ' + optionvalue);        
     });
    });
</script>
```

---

```
    <select onchange="" name="selectmenu" id="translator" class="selectmenu" >
     <option value="Select Language">Select The Language</option>
     <option value="en|af">Afrikaans</option>
     <option value="en|sq">Albanian</option>
     </select>
```

how can i get an alert from the first block of code? please note that `onSelectEvent:` in the first block of code is custom triggering event for option change.

thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Your first code will not `alert` because you are assigning `change` event to the `document` not to the drop down.

**EDIT : Comment Response**

Plugin has following two `option` use it.

> `onSelectEvent`
>
> A custom event handler for handling option selection. The function may take two parameters; the object (the link inside the option) clicked and the click-event, e.g.: `var customSelectHandler = function($obj, event){...};`. The default is null.
>
> `onSelectFunc`
>
> A function that will be called from within the default handler (at the beginning). The function may take two parameters; the object (the link inside the option) clicked and the click-event, e.g.: `var extraFunc = function($obj, event){...};`. The default is null.

Comment: but i have to call both the function together or one after another. i have to retrieve the option value and pass it on via cloned select menu, thanks,

Comment: @ Dipesh Parmar would you show me how to write the custom `onSelectEvent` in this case? i tried it in many ways. `onSelectEvent` in call function can't hold the function of clone select menu. thus, the clone select menu is lost and degraded to standard one. thanks,

Comment: opps! that was an accidental copy and paste mistake. i had been changing the call function continuously and the mistake was in the middle of that. however, i have updated my question and comment.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this one:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
   $(".selectmenu").scrollectBox({                           
      preset: 'dropdown',
      numVisibleOptions: 4,
      scrollInterval: 150, 
      scrollOn: 'hover',
      listWidth: 160,
      onSelectEvent: null
  }).change(function() { //<-------------------------------try it here.
     var optionvalue = $("option:selected", this).val();
     alert('Selected value ' + optionvalue); 
  });
});
```

Comment: Or just `this.value` and avoid the unnecessary use of jQuery. This, however, isn't an actual issue with the code; the end result would be the same.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Oh! i got it now. OP is giving the change event to the doc instead of select.

Comment: @Jai that was an accidental copy and paste mistake. i had been changing the call function continuously and the mistake was in the middle of that. i have updated my question. thanks,

Comment: @Jai i've tried `$("option:selected", this).val();` but it doesn't return any alert. i guess `.change(function()` may alert based on `onSelectEvent:`. any idea how to bind these together?

Answer (score 2):

You want to attach the event to the select box not the document.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){       
    $(".selectmenu").scrollectBox({                           
        // ...
    }).change(function() {
        var optionvalue = $("select.selectmenu").val(); 
        alert('Selected value ' + optionvalue); 
    });;    
})
```

jQuery's 'fluent' syntax always returns the object you're working with so you can chain together methods on the same selector.

You're also not getting the value for the selected option, as suggested by Jai:

```
var optionvalue = $("option:selected", this).val();
```

Comment: still optionvalue wont have the right value. see Jai's answer

Comment: @lordvlad If there's only *one* `<select class="selectmenu">` element on the page then it's totally fine. Also see my comment on Jai's answer, what he's suggested is overly complicated to get the value.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, you are right. sorry, I was quite sure that val() did not work on `<select>` but on `<option>`

Comment: @Tyriar that was an accidental copy and paste mistake. i had been changing the call function continuously and the mistake was in the middle of that. i have updated my question. thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Your first code should be something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){       
        $(".selectmenu").scrollectBox({                           
            preset: 'dropdown',
            numVisibleOptions: 4,
            scrollInterval: 150, 
            scrollOn: 'hover',
            listWidth: 160,
            onSelectEvent: null
       });    

        $(".selectmenu").change(function() {
           var optionvalue = $("select.selectmenu").val(); 
         alert('Selected value ' + optionvalue);        
         });

     });
    </script>
```

-------------------------EDITED--------------------------------

Script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
           var selectEvent = function($el){
            alert("You chose " + $el.html());
                return false;
            };
         $(".selectmenu").scrollectBox({                           
           preset: 'select',
            numVisibleOptions: 3,
            scrollOn: 'scroll',
            debug: true,
            onSelectEvent: selectEvent

         }); 
    });
</script>
```

Html:

```
 <select name="selectmenu" class="selectmenu" >
        <option>Select The Language</option>
        <option value="en|af">Afrikaans</option>
        <option value="en|sq">Albanian</option>
 </select>
```

PS: Tested on localhost :)

It's not working because you have the alert on the document change and not in the select menu change ;)

Saludos.

Comment: It really bugs me when cowards don't have the courage of their convictions and can't explain why they -1 an answer.  There's nothing wrong with this so I'm going to +1 to cancel out the stupid -1.

Comment: @Robert Rozas that was an accidental copy and paste mistake. i had been changing the call function continuously and the mistake was in the middle of that. i have updated my question. thanks,

Comment: @Robert Rozas i'm sure that your edited code must be returning option text like `Afrikaans` but not option value `en|af` in alert. i'm looking for a way to get option value but not text primarily and then pass it via cloned select menu when options are changed. thanks,

Comment: I tried every combination...nothing worked because the select its transformed into a div with ul and li elements....a cannot find the method to return the value instead of the html...i gonna give it a try a litlle more ,)

Answer (score 0):

you have an extra `})` closing bracket there

```
  $(".selectmenu").scrollectBox({                           
    preset: 'dropdown',
    numVisibleOptions: 4,
    scrollInterval: 150, 
    scrollOn: 'hover',
    listWidth: 160,
    onSelectEvent: null
});   
}).change(function() {
//^here..
   var optionvalue = $("select.selectmenu").val(); 
 alert('Selected value ' + optionvalue); 

 });
```

it should be

```
 $(".selectmenu").scrollectBox({                           
    preset: 'dropdown',
    numVisibleOptions: 4,
    scrollInterval: 150, 
    scrollOn: 'hover',
    listWidth: 160,
    onSelectEvent: null

 }).change(function() {....
```

Comment: that was an accidental copy and paste mistake. i had been changing the call function continuously and the mistake was in the middle of that. i have updated my question. thanks,